# Get random records distributed by categories

Tags: mysql

I need to get records from a table products, from several categories without run at risk of receiving records concentrated in few categories.

My sqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/060877/2

As you can see at SQLFiddle, I have 5 categories and 20 products (of course it's an example). I want to get, for example, 10 products without run at risk of receiving 5 or more products from category 2 and only 1 (or none) from 5.

If it's possible, return at proportion of quantity of each category (if 6 product, return 3 and so on).

Does MySQL make this automatically for me?

Comment: Maybe using a variable to set the proportion, and use as queries or subqueries to set the quantity in `LIMIT`

Comment: The limit is predefined

Comment: I mean for the subqueries

Answer (score 0):

What I meant (setting the limit as you need):

```
(SELECT p.*, c.name AS category 
FROM products AS p 
INNER JOIN category c ON p.category_id=c.id 
WHERE c.id = 1 LIMIT 6) 

UNION 

(SELECT p.*, c.name AS category 
FROM products AS p 
INNER JOIN category c ON p.category_id=c.id 
WHERE c.id = 2 LIMIT 3)

ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: This a bad idea. Low performance (5 selects), too much verbose... And don't solve the problem.

Comment: What I've understood: you're asking a limited number of rows from different categories... so: 1) set limit to the whole group (so you can't set specific limit to each category) **or** 2) set limit to each category = one subquery for each

Comment: Are you shure there's no other alternative?

Comment: To be honest this was my first idea, after that.. could be doing some maths to get a dynamic proportion but still using subqueries